# Load next Images via Ajax and add to Fancybox

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

My Problem is that I have a large gallery, that should not be load completely on first page load.
So I load 10 of 50 images and add fancybox to them.
When user clicks the next button, the 11th image should be loaded via Ajax and append to gallery container.

Problem ist that fancybox stops at the 10th image, because it doesn't know the dynamic load ones.

How can I add dynamic loaded images to fancybox2?

currently I have this:

```
function loadFancybox() {
    $('a.lightbox').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'
                }
            }
        },

        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).data('title');
            ajaxGetNextImages();
            loadFancybox();
        },
        loop: false
    });
}
loadFancybox();
```

`ajaxGetNextImages()` gets the next images :)

after that I call loadFancybox() so that all new images belongs to the gallery. But they aren't included until I reopen fancybox...

Comment: it works well when I close fancybox and reopen it. Then all dynamic loaded images are present in the gallery...

Comment: Fancybox is not designed to handle dynamic updates of the gallery items once is opened, **[CHECK THIS](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/257)** unless you come out with your own customized (and hacky) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, just for fun and based on [imran-a](https://github.com/imran-a)'s comment at this [GitHub](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/257) issue, here is your hacked solution :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    loop: false,
    beforeLoad: function () {
        if ((this.index == this.group.length - 1) && !done) {
            ajaxGetNextImages();
            done = true;
            this.group.push(
               { href: "images/04.jpg", type: "image", title: "Picture 04", isDom: false },
               { href: "images/05.jpg", type: "image", title: "Picture 05", isDom: false },
               { href: "images/06.jpg", type: "image", title: "Picture 06", isDom: false }
            ); // push 
        } // if
    } // beforeLoad
}); // fancybox
```

**NOTICE** that apart from calling `ajaxGetNextImages()` (which places the new images in the document flow) I had to push (manually) the new images inside the fancybox's group.

Is not a perfect solution but it works, see **[DEMO HERE](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadImagesinGalleryDynamically_19mar13.html)**; you will see three thumbnails at page load. Once you open fancybox and navigate to the last item, three more thumbnails will be added to the document as well as the 3 corresponding images to the fancybox gallery.

Also notice that you have to initialize `var done = false;` at the begining of your script.

BTW, forget about the function `loadFancybox()`,no needed.

Comment: Thanks!
But I don't get why this is not standard... isn't it a common requirement?

Comment: @Chrisn : is not a standard implementation because fancybox, as most plugins, is initialized after the DOM is ready and those items are not there yet so you have to "push" them. If you load them (via ajax) before fancybox starts, then they will be loaded in fancybox because it uses the `live` method.

Comment: is this works only to load images from ajax once ? i am trying ur code but its like it get image 0,1,2 and then 0,,1,2,3 next 0,1,2,3,4  i mean in loop it should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,

Comment: @simmisimmi not sure what you meant. The demo calls all the rest of the images after you reach the last of the initially loaded images. Then it loops through all of them

Comment: Thank you for this, this really put me on the right track for the solution I needed. For everybody who's trying to load additional images when clicking on the first image, check if ((this.group.length === 1)) - this will make sure that you only add additional images once.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `.fancybox();` again after loading images dynamically

Comment: I added some code to my op :) after images are appended to gallery container I already call .fancybox() on all items. But new images only appear when i reopen fancybox