# Fancybox - Add more images to gallery via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, fancybox, fancybox-2

I used [JFK's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) method for populating Fancybox 2.1.5 via Ajax instead of elements as shown here [FancyBox get href for images via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842741/fancybox-get-href-for-images-via-ajax)
This works quite nicely but the problem is there is no way to limit the amount of records called. If the gallery has 4000 images it will take a long time for Fancybox to load. 
So.. I limited my `SQL` query to `16 records`. Then I use a condition and function to tell fancybox to retrieve the next 16 records when it hits the last one in the current group. Problem is, it won't add the new images to the group. I'm using a method also [JFK's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) answer here [Load next Images via Ajax and add to Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500835/load-next-images-via-ajax-and-add-to-fancybox) to add to Fancybox's group using the `$fancybox.group.push` which isn't work for me.

First, here is the jQuery code to retrieve the additional images via `json`. the variable `pid` is the photo id that the database will start at when retrieving the next 16 records by the way. `a_id` is the album. This function is being called **inside** of fancybox's `afterLoad` function where the rest of my code is. It was too long to post all of it. The push function is called when the custom next arrow is clicked using `onclick();`

```
function push(pid, a_id){

        var act = "thtr";
        var module = "photos";
        var push = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: {"a_id": a_id, "act": act, "pid": pid, "push": push, "module": module},
            success: function(response){    
             var arrayObj = $.parseJSON(response);
             $.fancybox.group.push(arrayObj);
             alert($.fancybox.group.length);
             $.fancybox.next();
            }
        });
}
```

The `$fancy.group.push` is not working. The ajax response I get is the same as the initial ajax response when fancybox is first opened except it's 16 new records.
The `json` response is formatted like below. BTW there are a few extra items in the `json` response that I use for other things, which is ignored otherwise so that's not a problem. The group initially has 16 records but after I run the `push` function, it alerts back `17` but nothing changed. It should alert back `32` if it pulled another `16` or however many the server responds with. Not sure why it's not working. Can't find anything else on adding to a group.

```
[{"href":"https:\/\/cdn1.mysite.com\/photos\/c5\/c7\/45\/c5c745a424b9a2f.jpeg","type":"image","pid":"77695","owner":"12219","purl":"https:\/\/mysite.com\/photo?per=12219&set=77695.15735&s=0","aurl":"\/view-photo_album-1jpIbSZgIsV.html","isDom":false},...etc]
```

**UPDATE**

The group is being updated using `$.fancybox.group.push` as an alert is showing 32 objects in it now. But for some reason, fancybox is not being updated because hitting next loops over instead of going to the new image.

**UPDATE2**

The push works if I manually write out the response string into the function like this example:

```
$.fancybox.group.push(
               { href: "images/04.jpg", type: "image", title: "Picture 04", isDom: false },
               { href: "images/05.jpg", type: "image", title: "Picture 05", isDom: false }
);
```

Not sure why it won't work with the variable like this. It has too come from the response.

```
$.fancybox.group.push(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out looking at other JSON response questions. For whatever reason using the `$.fancybox.group.push` method using a variable only seems to work if you iterate through the object with `$.each`. Hopefully this might help someone else out who wants a fully ajaxed Fancybox.

Here is my completed function.

```
function do_push(pid, a_id){

        var act = "thtr";
        var module = "photos";
        var gpush = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: {"a_id": a_id, "act": act, "pid": pid, "push": gpush, "module": module},
            success: function(response){    
             var arrayObj = $.parseJSON(response);
             $.each(arrayObj, function(index){
                $.fancybox.group.push(arrayObj[index]);
             });
             $.fancybox.next();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You should simply change ajax dataType like this **dataType: "json" **

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Fancybox 2.x the simply use this solution:

Json Response

```
{"images":[{"href":"images/04.jpg","type":"image","title":"Picture 04","isDom":"false"}, {"href":"images/05.jpg","type":"image","title":"Picture 05","isDom":"false"}]}
```

Javascript Function

```
function do_push(pid, a_id){
        var act = "thtr";
        var module = "photos";
        var gpush = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"a_id": a_id, "act": act, "pid": pid, "push": gpush,"module": module},
            success: function(response){    
                $.fancybox(response.images);
            }
        });
}
```