# Can multiple fancybox configurations for multiple galleries be combined into a single script tag?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

We have two fancybox galleries on the same page and both share the same config options - but one gallery is created manually and the other uses the usual fancybox thumbs to trigger the overlay.

**Question 1:**

Is there a way to combine the shared config options, attach them to the galleries that were clicked and still build one of the galleries manually?

**Question 2:**

The gallery which is built manually is output using php - is there a way to have php output commas but leave the comma off the last image?

We've left the last image out of the loop as per below but it obviously outputs twice (we're using the kirby CMS) - and below that is all the fancybox configuration we'd like shared between both galleries:

```
$(function() {
  $(".product-main-gallery").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open([

      <? foreach($page->images() as $image): ?>

      {
        href : '<?= $image->url() ?>',
        rel : 'product-main-gallery'
      },

      <? endforeach ?>

      {
        href : '<?= $page->images()->last()->url(); ?>',
        rel : 'product-main-gallery'
      }
      ], {
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        nextSpeed : 'slow',
        prevSpeed : 'slow',
        arrows : 'true',

        // configure overlay style
        padding    : 0,
        margin     : 0,
        autoCenter : false,

        helpers : {

          // configure overlay colour
          overlay : {
            css : {
              'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'
            }
          }
        },

        // Force overlay image to full screen
        // http://jsfiddle.net/2XhjG/
        afterLoad  : function () {
          $.extend(this, {
            aspectRatio : false,
            type    : 'html',
            width   : '100%',
            height  : '100%',
            content : '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + this.href + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>'
          });
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: why don't you place your php output in an array and then push the array into the existing fancybox gallery? ...another question: should the php gallery go before or after the existing gallery?

Comment: Thanks @JFK - both galleries are output using php - but one of them is output using the fancybox 'manual' method so that no thumbs load (it's triggered with a button). My PHP/JS skills are limited so I don't understand how to output the gallery as an array and push it to fancybox sorry.

Comment: Understand, it doesn't really matter there are not thumbs. I meant, instead of placing the php's `foreach` function inside `$.fancybox.open()` method, output each `<?= $image->url() ?>` in array, then push that array into the fancybox group. Here a link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/15507334/1055987