# Loading images dynamically in fancyBox using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I use [fancyBox3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) for displaying image in a gallery and load images at the same time. But as loading 500 or more images at the same time is no plausible, I want to display 10 images on page load and display the others 10 by 10. There are some examples on the web but none of them is suitable for this approach. I can load images via AJAX, but need to load more on the related event (when clicking Next on the last image for example) by appending the fetched data to the gallery. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You have experienced fancy as on some of your post.. What about this problem???

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/15507334/1055987 ...although is for v2.1.x it will give you the idea

Comment: @JFK Yes, I had checked and tried it before asking the question. But it did not solved my problem, because there is a method like **ajaxGetNextImages();** and something I am missing. So, **could you please post a full example as answer to my post?**

Comment: The script actually loads and contains 3-5 images at the same time. If you would disable thumbnail module, it might work ok (have not tested).

Comment: @Janis How to do this??? **Why do not you post an example as answer???**